# NextJs14 app router Cookie Authentification redirect

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, next.js

I need your help with my NextJS app. I want to implement redirect authentification in NextJS and created
[this simple mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2gRL.png).

this is my app/page.tsx:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { getSession, login, logout } from "@/lib/lib";
import Login from "@/components/login"
export default async function Home() {
  const session = await getSession();
  console.log(session)
  return (
    <main className="container relative mx-auto scroll-my-12 overflow-auto p-4 print:p-12 md:p-16">
      <section className="mx-auto w-full max-w-4xl space-y-8 dark:bg-transparent print:space-y-6">
        <form
          action={async () => {
            "use server";
            await login();
          }}
        >
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Login with Speckle</button>
        </form>
        <form
          action={async () => {
            "use server";
            await logout();
            redirect("/");
          }}
        >
          <button type="submit">Logout</button>
        </form>
        
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>
      </section>
      <section className="mx-auto w-full max-w-4xl space-y-8 dark:bg-transparent print:space-y-6">

      
      </section>

    </main>
  );
}
```

and this is where I handle my login lib/lib.tsx:

```
import { SignJWT, jwtVerify } from "jose";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import React from 'react'


export const APP_NAME = "SpeckleReactDemo";
export const TOKEN = `${APP_NAME}.AuthToken`;
export const REFRESH_TOKEN = `${APP_NAME}.RefreshToken`;
export const CHALLENGE = `${APP_NAME}.Challenge`;

export const SERVER_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL ?? "https://speckle.xyz";
const SPECKLE_APP_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID ?? "c62cgebsa6ds";
const SPECKLE_APP_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_APP_SECRET ?? "90234756db45";

const secretKey = "secret";
const key = new TextEncoder().encode(secretKey);

// Define the interface
export interface AuthContextType {
  token: string | null;
  refreshToken: string | null;
  login: () => void;
  exchangeAccessCode: (accessCode: string) => Promise<void>;
  logOut: () => void;
}


export async function encrypt(payload: any) {
  return new SignJWT(payload)
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
    .setIssuedAt()
    .setExpirationTime("2h") // Consider setting a longer expiration time for practical use
    .sign(key);
}

export async function decrypt(input: string): Promise<any> {
  const { payload } = await jwtVerify(input, key, {
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
  });
  return payload;
}

export async function login() {

  // Create the session
  const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000);
  const session = await encrypt({ expires });
  // Generate random challenge
  var challenge =
    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  // Save challenge in localStorage
  cookies().set(CHALLENGE, challenge);
  const redirectUri = `${SERVER_URL}/api/speckle-callback`; // Adjust with your actual redirect URI
  const speckleAuthUrl = `${SERVER_URL}/authn/verify/${SPECKLE_APP_ID}/${challenge}?redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUri)}`;
  redirect(speckleAuthUrl);
  cookies().set("session", session, { expires, httpOnly: true });
}

export async function logout() {
  // Destroy the session
  cookies().set("session", "", { expires: new Date(0) });
}

export async function getSession() {
  const session = cookies().get("session")?.value;
  if (!session) return null;
  return await decrypt(session);
}

export async function updateSession(request: NextRequest) {
  const session = request.cookies.get("session")?.value;
  if (!session) return;

  // Refresh the session so it doesn't expire
  const parsed = await decrypt(session);
  parsed.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000);
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  res.cookies.set({
    name: "session",
    value: await encrypt(parsed),
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: parsed.expires,
  });
  return res;
}

export async function exchangeAccessCode(accessCode: string): Promise<{ token: string, refreshToken: string }> {
  // Get the token and refreshToken from localStorage
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(cookies().get(TOKEN));
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = React.useState(
    cookies().get(REFRESH_TOKEN)
  );

  var res = await fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/auth/token/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      accessCode: accessCode,
      appId: SPECKLE_APP_ID,
      appSecret: SPECKLE_APP_SECRET,
      challenge: cookies().get(CHALLENGE),
    }),
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to exchange access code for tokens');
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  //return { token: data.token, refreshToken: data.refreshToken };


  if (data.token) {
    // If retrieving the token was successful, remove challenge and set the new token and refresh token

    cookies().set(TOKEN, data.token, { secure: true });
    cookies().set(REFRESH_TOKEN, data.refreshToken, { secure: true,     httpOnly: true    });

    cookies().delete(CHALLENGE);
    cookies().set(TOKEN, data.token);
    cookies().set(REFRESH_TOKEN, data.refreshToken);
    setToken(data.token);
    setRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);
  }
};
```

and I try to handle the exchange here:

```
// pages/api/speckle-callback.ts
import { exchangeAccessCode } from '@/lib/lib';
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function handler(req: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(req.url);
  const code = requestUrl.searchParams.get("access_code");

  if (!code || typeof code !== 'string') {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Authorization code is required.' }), {
      status: 400,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }

  try {
    const { token, refreshToken } = await exchangeAccessCode(code);

    // Create a response object to redirect
    const response = NextResponse.redirect('/');
    // Securely set tokens in HTTPOnly cookies
    response.cookies.set('token', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, path: '/', maxAge: 3600 });
    response.cookies.set('refreshToken', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, path: '/', maxAge: 86400 });

    return response;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exchanging access code:', error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }), {
      status: 500,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

It return a access-code in my url bar but I want it to be handled on server side for security, and I think I don't follow the best practice. Anybody who can help me with this

NextJS simple setup cookies()